# Android trackball events while screen is off

Tags: android, trackball

I'm looking for a way to grab trackball events while the screen is off, preferrably on a N1. I'm building my own music player and would love to add the feature to skip songs by trackball press, without having to unlock my device everytime.

I've found [TrackBallSkip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=645481), however the source code has been taken down and integrated into CyanogenMod. I fear that I may need to do something exotic to my phone (root it, mod it, whatever). While this isn't a problem, I would be happier if I could freely share my Music player.

Can anyone confirm that I'll need to mod the home to get access to this functionality? Or can I just straight code it (if so, any pointers in the right direction would be amazing).

Thanks!

Comment: That would be really annoying, having songs skip by accidentally when it's in your pocket

Comment: @Falmarri - True, I wouldn't be happy about that either, but then I guess we're not part of the target demographic that would use this feature.  Different types of people could love it, if it were available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where Cyanogen put TrackBallSkip into their source base ([this commit](http://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_policies_base/commit/58648b22b02bda0ae1a712473a174c6c969e9584)). It appears to reside in `phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java` which means it can't be implemented without modding the firmware (since the related package resides in `/system`).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I won't be adding this feature:(